# CWD in vsCode / sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I created a workspace in vsCode at `path/to/workspace` and started using `sqlite3.connect("data.db")`. My first database would be created correctly - but after doing so again in another folder `path/to/workspace/subfolder` ,
`sqlite3.connect("data.db")` would still connect to the db at `path/to/workspace`.

`os.path.abspath(".")` returns `path/to/workspace` in the scripts of both directories, so the cwd just remains the directory of the workspace.

(1) Why is the cwd of an executed script not the path to the script but rather the path to the workspace? / Why doesn't sqlite3 simply connect to databases relative to the path to the script that is executed?

I found that I can solve that with `os`:

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

con = sqlite3.connect(path + "\data.db")
```

(2) Is that approach a safe way to handle that problem also considering the portability of a project?

Comment: The `cwd` of a script is the current directory of the process that actually launched the script. When you start the script from a shell, it is well defined and is the current directory of the shell. When you start a script from an IDE, it is what the IDE decided, and is often not what the user would have expected. Just look on SO the number of questions about *I cannot open or find my file*. Ideally, data files should not reside in the script source directory, but it can be unconvenient for trivial scripts. For that reason, you should use absolute paths of paths or paths relative to `__file__`

Answer (score 0):

Which `cwd` you get in the script depends on the `cwd` in the terminal, in other words, the routs in the terminal where you execute your script. For example:

[image]

If you want to change the route to the parent folder of the script you want to execute when you create a new terminal, you can add this in the settings.json file:

```
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
```

But it does not work when you execute the command of `Run Python File in Terminal`, because the terminal was created by the `Python` extension, you can add this in the settings.json file to achieve it:

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
```

And you can add this in the launch.json file to modify the route in debugging mode:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

But both of the above methods were not recommended, Remain the `cwd` to the workspace can make the structure clearly.

Comment: @nikita_44 Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )